# Thunderbird reply break

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-signature

By default, thunderbird puts no breaks between the content and the signature when composing a new message.

```
content
signature
```

If I put a single break in my signature, when I compose a new message the content and signature are separated by a break.

```
content

my signature
```

But when I reply to a message, another separating break is automatically added.

```
content


my signature
```

Id like the content to be preceded by a single break under all circumstances. How can I achieve this?